# Json Data from datatable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net

Here i have a problem with data table to convert json. This is my class called `SearchCollection`

```
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
public string CategoryName { get; set; }
public int ClassGroupId { get; set; }
public string ClassName { get; set; }
public int ClassNumber { get; set; }
public int BookTypeId { get; set; }
public string BookType { get; set; }
```

I have collected a data from store procedure and pushed into the datatable, thats why am using       `ConvertToDatatable()`, that time i got a datatable which contains 3 tables data

```
static DataTable ConvertToDatatable(IEnumerable<SearchCollection> list)    
{

    var dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("CategoryId");
    dt.Columns.Add("CategoryName");
    dt.Columns.Add("ClassGroupId");
    dt.Columns.Add("ClassName");
    dt.Columns.Add("ClassNumber");
    dt.Columns.Add("BookTypeId");
    dt.Columns.Add("BookType");

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();

        row["CategoryId"] = item.CategoryId;
        row["CategoryName"] = item.CategoryName;
        row["ClassGroupId"] = item.ClassGroupId;
        row["ClassName"] = item.ClassName;
        row["ClassNumber"] = item.ClassNumber;
        row["BookTypeId"] = item.BookTypeId;
        row["BookType"] = item.BookType;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

this contain 3 tables data.

So.. this is have tried to group the data, but here am getting the answer like category on top inside category shows booktype and inside booktype shows list of classnames, but i want 3 set of data
category {},booktype{},classnames{}

```
var result = rows.GroupBy(r => new { x = r["CategoryId"], y = r["CategoryName"] }).Select(g => new
{
    CategoryId = g.Key.x,
    CategoryName = g.Key.y,
    BookTypes = g.GroupBy(r => new { h = r["BookTypeId"], i = r["BookType"] }).Select(g1 => new
    {
        BookTypeId = g1.Key.h,
        BookType = g1.Key.i,
        ClassNames = g1.Select(r => new
        {
            ClassGroupId = r["ClassGroupId"],
            ClassName = r["ClassName"],
            ClassNumber = r["ClassNumber"]
        }),
    }),
});



     Rusult
This is my result
{    CategoryId:1   CategoryName:CD     ClassGroupId:15     ClassName:I     ClassNumber:1   BookTypeId:1    BookType:General CD}
{    CategoryId:2   CategoryName:DVD     ClassGroupId:16    ClassName:II    ClassNumber:2   BookTypeId:2    BookType:General DVD}
{    CategoryId:3   CategoryName:Book    ClassGroupId:17    ClassName:III   ClassNumber:3   BookTypeId:3    BookType:General Books}

 But i want the result like this   

+ Category={ CategoryId:1   CategoryName:CD     
    CategoryId:2    CategoryName:DVD    
    CategoryId:3    CategoryName:Book    }

   ClassGroup={ClassGroupId:15  ClassName:I     ClassNumber:1
    ClassGroupId:16     ClassName:II    ClassNumber:2
    ClassGroupId:17     ClassName:III   ClassNumber:3}

BookType{  BookTypeId:1 BookType:General CD
    BookTypeId:2    BookType:General DVD
    BookTypeId:3    BookType:General Books
}
```

here my result is booktype is under category and classname under booktype. but i want the result just like 3  groups of records in single json, any one help just like category grouped collection, class grouped collection and book type collection in single json data.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide an example of the data you have in the DataTable and the JSON result you want to create from that data?  It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: i have updated my question can u please check..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
    var result = new
    {
        Category = rows
            .GroupBy(r => new 
            { 
                x = r["CategoryId"],
                y = r["CategoryName"] 
            })
            .Select(g => new 
            { 
                CategoryId = g.Key.x,
                CategoryName = g.Key.y 
            }),
        ClassGroup = rows
            .GroupBy(r => new
            {
                x = r["ClassGroupId"],
                y = r["ClassName"],
                z = r["ClassNumber"]
            })
            .Select(g => new
            {
                ClassGroupId = g.Key.x,
                ClassName = g.Key.y,
                ClassNumber = g.Key.z
            }),
        BookType = rows
            .GroupBy(r => new
            {
                x = r["BookTypeId"],
                y = r["BookType"]
            })
            .Select(g => new
            {
                BookTypeId = g.Key.x,
                BookType = g.Key.y
            })
    };
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/h9qXqc